# How do I create sub-headers in python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have a dataframe say:

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Item': ['California', '2012%', '2013%','Arizona','2012%','%2019','Janu%ary'], 
                   'col1': [0,50, 50,0,10,11,14],'col2': [0, 50, 40,0,15,13,15]})
Output=
    Item  col1 col2
  1  California  0    0
  2  2012%  50   50
  3  2013%  40   40
  4  Arizona  0   0
  5  2012%.    10. 15
  6. %2019.    11. 13
  7. Janu%ary.  14. 15
```

I want the column names like " California" and "Arizona" (the ones that do not have "%" in the column values to be considered as Headers that has to be appended to their respective sub-headers. Like maybe iterate down the rows and find a pattern e.g. without ‘%’ in row means its a header, with ‘%’ means its a sub-header
then for the ‘sub-header’ rows, add the last found ‘header’.

```
 Expected output=
    Item  col1 col2
  
  1  California 2012%  50   50
  2  California 2013%  40   40
  3  Arizona 2012%.    10. 15
  4  Arizona 2019%.    11. 13
  5 Arizona January%.  14. 15
```

Comment: the provided input does not match the text input, you have to clarify

Comment: @mozway I have corrected it

Comment: Also the `California`/`California%`

Comment: @mozway Yup! I fixed it

Comment: There is a syntax error in the input data. The correct input data for example provided could be the following: `{"Item": ["California%", "2012%", "2013%", "Arizona", "2012%", "2019%", "January%"],  "col1": [0, 20, 50, 40, 0, 10, 11], "col2": [0, 20, 50, 40, 0, 15, 13]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you could use a mask and perform boolean masking/indexing:

```
# does the name contains '%' (you could use other conditions)
m = df['Item'].str.contains('%')
# mask and ffill the "header", then concatenate
df['Item'] = df['Item'].mask(m).ffill() + ' ' + df['Item']

# drop the former header rows
df = df.loc[m]
```

output:

```
               Item  col1  col2
1  California 2012%    50    50
2  California 2013%    50    40
4     Arizona 2012%    10    15
5     Arizona 2019%    11    13
6  Arizona January%    14    15
```

###### alternative to have a real index:

```
m = df['Item'].str.contains('%')
df['index'] = df['Item'].mask(m).ffill()

df = df.loc[m].set_index('index')
```

output:

```
                Item  col1  col2
index                           
California     2012%    50    50
California     2013%    50    40
Arizona        2012%    10    15
Arizona        2019%    11    13
Arizona     January%    14    15
```

Comment: Not just ends with %, the "%" can be anywhere. Let me edit the question.

Comment: @ShruthiRavishankar then use `str.contains`, see update